# How can I take a field of an array and confirm it against another field?

Tags: php, html, arrays, csv

How do i match one field in an array to another in PHP?
This is the script I'm using for a random line:

```
<?php

$sep=","; // separator 
$mycsv=file("csv/all.csv"); 
$row=rand(0,count($mycsv)-1); 
$data=explode($sep,$mycsv[$row]); 

$num = count ($data); 

for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { 
  print $data[$c] . "<br>"; 
} 

?>
```

My CSV format:

```
Category Value Question Answer
```

Currently, I've got it so the index.php calls for random_csv_line.php just for testing purposes. On load, it shows entire random line at top.

I'm trying to have it load Value and Question, and return a true/false response when I enter answer into a single text field form. I believe this would mean loading the array into a session but I can't find any reference on how to individual fields of an array line.

Comment: Note: Random script code is not mine. It's from here on stackoverflow (if i remember).